# Create custom test folder with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

So far I have the two default folders:

- src/test
- src/androidTest

I would like to add a new one to write other tests that will. To do so I've created the folder:

- src/deviceIntegrationTest

And added in gradle:

```
android{
    // ...
    sourceSets {
        deviceIntegrationTest{
            java.srcDirs = [
                    'src/main/java',
                    'src/deviceIntegrationTest/java',
                    'src/deviceIntegrationTest/java/'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But android studio does not list this folder when I use the Android project view. And I cannot add java class neither..

Is it possible to do want I want ?

Answer (score 0):

try to change your code like that :

```
sourceSets{
    integrationTest {
        java {
            srcDirs = [
                'src/main/java',
                'src/iotizeDeviceIntegrationTest/java',
                'src/iotizeDeviceIntegrationTest/java/'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```